# dynmically created radiobuttonlist clears the selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, postback

I have 2 radiobuttonlist2. When the user selects one of them, it automatically postbacks and it clears the selection of the other radiobuttonlist. how can I fix this?

this is the radiobuttonlist which its selection gets cleared

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl_odeme_secenekleri" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbl_odeme_secenekleri_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

here is how I load items to the radiobuttonlist above

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        double total = Convert.ToDouble(txt_total.Text);
        double total_with_discount = total * 0.94;
        rbl_odeme_secenekleri.Items.Add(new ListItem("Tek Çekim(%6 indrimli): " + Math.Round(total_with_discount,2) + " TL",  Math.Round(total_with_discount,2) + ""));
        rbl_odeme_secenekleri.Items.Add(new ListItem("Taksitli: " + total + " TL", total + ""));
        rbl_odeme_secenekleri.SelectedIndex = 0;

    }
```

I am checking if (!IsPostBack), so it shouldnt get cleared. any idea?

Comment: seems like ViewState disabled.

Comment: I checked it and it is enabled already

Comment: what are you trying to do in the radio button changed event? please paste that code too. If you add or remove controls in change event, then viewstate may not match with the new html and it may not initialize the controls properly.

Comment: show me your `rbl_odeme_secenekleri_SelectedIndexChanged` code !

Comment: I removed that function. It doesnt exist anymore. But it still behaves the same way. It clears the selection

Comment: Remove the code inside the change event and try again. The problem won't happen again.

Comment: You don't want to remove rbl_odeme_secenekleri_SelectedIndexChanged function. You want to remove the radibuttonindexchanged function which caused the postback. rbl_odeme_secenekleri_SelectedIndexChanged function doesn't make sense because the autopostback is set to false. give a try

Comment: I want the page to be post back when user make a selection on the X radiobuttonlist, but I dont want rbl_odeme_secenekleri's selection to be cleared